# Every smooth curve is solution of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$-function with $\gamma(t)\neq 0\ \forall t\in \Bbb{R}$. Then I want to show that there exists a continous function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \text{End}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ such that $\dot{\gamma}(t)=f(t)\gamma(t).$

For $n=1$ one can simply choose $f(t):=\frac{\dot{\gamma}(t)}{\gamma(t)}$. But what can I do in higher dimensions? I tried to apply the implicit function theorem but to apply it one needs that $A(x,t):=\dot{\gamma}(t)-x\gamma(t)$ is $C^1$, but our hypothesis only yields that this function is continuous.

Any help will be greatful appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you can rephrase the problem as

> given continuous functions $\def\RR{\mathbb R}\alpha$, $\beta:\RR\to\RR^n$, with $\beta$ nowhere zero, there exists a continuous $A:\RR\to End(\RR^n)$ such that $\alpha(t)=A(t)(\beta(t))$ for all $t\in\RR$,

as you can then take $\alpha=\gamma'$ and $\beta=\gamma$. This shows that the problem is not really about ODEs!

To solve this for of the problem, we may take $\displaystyle A(t)(v)=\frac{\langle v,\beta(t)\rangle}{\langle\beta(t),\beta(t)\rangle}\alpha(t)$.

Comment: Ah!!! Thank you so much for clarifying. Somehow the solution of the (more general) rephrased question appears easier to me.